# Aggregator tool for multiple heterogeneous bug/issue trackers?

Tags: web-applications, aggregate, collaboration, issue-tracking

I do software development with a team as a part of my graduate research. We are involved in a number of projects hosted in various places: some on public GitHub projects, some on a private Redmine instance, etc. Some logical projects are split into multiple project repositories, often with some public parts and some private parts. We're using the issue tracker for each project for its respective hosting location, which is good except that we now have a lot of places to check and I'm worried we're approaching "tool overload" - too many places to report a bug, too many places to check for bug reports.

So, the question is: Is there an aggregator tool/web app that we could configure to show us at least a combined bug list from multiple different bug trackers? It would be nice if it could also show a combined "activity feed" (as both GitHub and Redmine offer), and even better if we could add 'one-off' external bugs to track (something in an upstream bugzilla, for instance) but now I'm really getting into dreamland.

**"Me too" update 2013-02-14:**

I was going to post a question which is clearly a duplicate of this.  Since it's not got an accepted answer (and neither of the answers seem particularly satisfactory), I'll extend this one:

I'm dealing with multiple teams (over multiple sites) each using different issue trackers (all of Redmine, Jira, FogBugz and Trac of interest currently).  I have web access to the trackers and the issues in which I'm interested in each tracker are generally quite good about cross referencing related issues in other trackers (ideally in a custom field).

Are there any tools out there which will somehow present a more unified view of a particular project effectively spread across multiple teams than I'm getting at the moment from having multiple browser windows opened?

An example of the sort of workflow I'm trying to improve would be spotting issues that one team claim to have fixed but the downstream dependent team need prodding to pick it up and validate it, or spotting when downstream have decided something isn't needed any more but not notified the upstream.

Note that processes, policies and politics are such that there is no hope everyone will agree to use one common tracker somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any ready-to-run aggregator tools, but you should be able to use [Ticketmaster](http://ticketrb.com/) to build your own as it provides a consistent interface into various providers including github and redmine.

Comment: This seems like the closest so far. Note that it's now called [Taskmapper](http://ticketrb.com/) which simultaneously uses fewer trademarks and is more clear.

Comment: You could also remove the answer as the domain is out and the project is not abandonware.

Comment: See my answer for a solution that works and that's not abandoned. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43557057/99834

Comment: @sorin I'm assuming you meant `... the project is now abandonware`?

Answer (score 1):

The only tool that I am aware of being able to aggregate/consolidate list of tickets from different issue trackers is [BugWarrior](https://github.com/ralphbean/bugwarrior)

I used it a little bit but didn't have time to get a clear opinion regarding its maturity. One thing that put me off a little bit was the lack of a GUI. There are some graphical interfaces on top of it but I wasn't able to find a cool one for OS X, yet.

I *confirm* that I was able to make it gather data from *multiple* instances of:

- Gerrit
- JIRA
- BugZilla
- GitHub
- GitLab

For a complete list check its main page.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.tasktop.com and http://www.opshub.com/main/ might do that although I have never used them.

Comment: This seems like it might meet @timday's needs - commercial, proprietary service focused on integrating groups of a dev firm. My issue was slightly different (integrating multiple projects with diverse hosting) but similar, and I apparently didn't state my hope that it would be open-source or at least no-charge.

Comment: Thanks, yes these look quite interesting (to me), although there appears to be more of an emphasis on syncing state between trackers (c.f just getting some unified view) than I'd have expected was actually feasible (the thought of having to sort out conflicts from automatic tracker merges... groan).  I also came across https://zapier.com/ which has some support for github & redmine amongst other things and looks like it could be used to cook up some sort of activity feed from multiple sources.